# What is the syntax for inserting data into a timestamp(6) type field in Oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle, records

I need to insert some data into a table in Oracle.

The only problem is one of the fields is a timestamp(6) type and it is required data. I don't care about what actually goes in here I just need to get the right syntax for an entry so that the database will accept it.

I'm using the gui web client to enter data however I don't mind using raw SQL if I have to.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking how to create a column with TIMESTAMP datatype, or how to convert a string value to a TIMESTAMP value when inserting or loading?

Comment: I think I have worded this poorly. I need to insert data into a timestamp column.

Answer (score 11):

I dunno if this helps at all, but in SQL*Plus I did this:

```
create table x ( a timestamp(6));
insert into x values ( current_timestamp );
select * from x;
```

getting me this:

```
T
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
15-OCT-08 02.01.25.604309 PM
```

So it looks like that works.

If you need to put a previously-known value into the column, how about the TO_TIMESTAMP() function? Something like this:

```
select to_timestamp('27/02/2002 15:51.12.539880', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi.ss.ff') 
from dual ;
```

Comment: the to_timestamp function didn't work for me in this particular case (the database client didn't like it) - but it seems like a good way to create timestamp values. Thanks.

Comment: Many thanks... This just saved me in an urgent, time sensitive moment!  Can't say I've ever found any Oracle documentaion about which I can say the same!!

Answer (score 5):

using `to_timestamp()` is one option.
the other is doing this:

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES (timestamp'2009-09-09 09:30:25 CET');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of different TO_TIMESTAMP functions that worked for me...

This TO_TIMESTAMP function worked on an INSERT against a column of type TIMESTAMP(6):

```
TO_TIMESTAMP('04/14/2015 2:25:55','mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi.ss.ff')
```

This TO_TIMESTAMP function worked on an INSERT against a column of type DATE:

```
TO_TIMESTAMP('04/15/2015','mm/dd/yyyy')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into x values(to_timestamp('22:20:00','hh24:mi'));
```